# Jmeter remote Execution -- Is there any way to provide global property from ant?

Tags: ant, jmeter, jmeter-plugins

In my Jmeter script
I'm using property function i.e. ${__P(varName,2)} to specify variable value at run time.

When Executing script from CMD -- 
I can specify property value  using  -JvarName (i.e. -JvarName=5)  and 
for remote Execution I can specify value using -GvarName (i.e. -GvarName=5)
from CMD.

Now I'm trying to run this Jmeter script using [ant build](http://www.programmerplanet.org/projects/jmeter-ant-task/)
and
It's working fine on single PC. (i.e. runremote="false")
But when I try to execute remotely on multiple PC  (i.e. runremote="true")
It Doesn't take values provided in property tag (i.e.`<property name="varName" value="5"/>`)
is there any way to provide global property from ant.??
just like we do from CMD using argument  -G .

```
<target name="JMeter" depends="start"> 
  <taskdef name="jmeter"    
        classname="org.programmerplanet.ant.taskdefs.jmeter.JMeterTask">    
  </taskdef> 
  <jmeter jmeterhome="${jmeter_Home}"   
         resultlog="${report.output.location}/Report/${property.file}/${START_TIME}/JMete‌​rSummeryResults.jtl" 
         runremote="true"> 
      <testplans dir="../JMeter" includes="*.jmx" /> 
      <property name="USERS" value="${thread.users}" /> 
      <property name="SITE_ID" value="${site.id}" /> 
      <property name="FOLDER_ID" value="${folder.id}" /> 
      <property name="FILE_PATH" value="${file.upload.path}" /> 
  </jmeter>
```

Comment: can you show your ant code ?

Comment: `<target name="JMeter" depends="start">`
`<taskdef name="jmeter"` `classname="org.programmerplanet.ant.taskdefs.jmeter.JMeterTask">` `</taskdef>`
`<jmeter jmeterhome="${jmeter_Home}" resultlog="${report.output.location}/Report/${property.file}/${START_TIME}/JMeterSummeryResults.jtl" runremote="true">`
  `<testplans dir="../JMeter" includes="*.jmx" />`
  `<property name="USERS" value="${thread.users}" />`
  `<property name="SITE_ID" value="${site.id}" />`
  `<property name="FOLDER_ID" value="${folder.id}" />`
  `<property name="FILE_PATH" value="${file.upload.path}" />`
 `</jmeter>`
`</target>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a `remote` attribute which needs to be set to `true`.

`<property name="varName" value="5" remote="true"/>`